# implement google search overlay on google map, on click of actionbar search icon in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying to implement google search overlay on google map, after calling the google search view it is disappearing within a .`second.Please need a help.
 public void findSearchPlace()
{
try
{
Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.ModeFullscreen).Build(this.Activity);
            StartActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e)
        {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        }
        catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e)
        {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        }
    }`

Comment: First, please make sure your target device has google service. And could you please post the codes of `OnActivityResult`? It could be the codes in `OnActivityResult` that crash the overlay.

Comment: Thank You @Elvis :) i have implemented it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install package named Xamarin Google Play Services - Places
2. Include Google Places APIWebService key in ManifestFile
   `<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
     android:value="**Your Google Places APIWebService key**"/>`.

>

```
using Android.Gms.Location.Places;
namespace com.companyname.projectname
{
 //function for actionbar  searchIcon
public void findSearchPlace()
    {
        try
        {
            Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.ModeFullscreen).Build(this.Activity);

            StartActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e)
        {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        }
        catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e)
        {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        }
    }

    public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                IPlace place = PlaceAutocomplete.GetPlace(this.Activity, data);
                LatLng latlng = place.LatLng;//getting alat lon from google server
                try
                {
                    map.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(latlng, 17));


                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }

            }
            else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.ResultError)
            {

                // TODO: Handle the error.

            }
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
            {
                // The user canceled the operation.
            }
        }
    }
```

***code***
}